# Jquery. Вызвать функцию при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Всем привет. Не силен в JS, помогите разобраться

**Дано:**
Имеется функция JS которая вызывает список городов. Подключается в **header** ввиде **js** файла

```
GeoIPModule.prototype.loadCities = function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        if (!this.citiesLoaded) {
            $.ajax({
                url:      self.http_host + 'index.php?route=extension/module/geoip/getList',
                dataType: 'html',
                success:  function(html) {
                    self.chooseBlock.html(html);
                    var input = self.chooseBlock.find('.geoip-popup-input');
                    self.autocomplete(input, self.chooseBlock.find('.geoip-body'));
                    input.siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').css({'maxHeight': 300, 'overflowY': 'auto', 'overflowX': 'hidden'});
                    input.focus();
                    self.citiesLoaded = true;
                    callback.apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**Задача:**
Необходимо вызвать функцию, т.е. вызвать список городов, при нажатии на ссылку в любой части документа

Пытаюсь сделать это:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="load-сities">ССЫЛКА</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#load-сities").click(function(e) {
    GeoIPModule.prototype.loadCities();
  });
</script>
```

Но получаю ошибку: **ReferenceError: GeoIPModule is not defined**

**Полный скрипт** [jsfiddle.net/3L604e7m](https://jsfiddle.net/3L604e7m)

Answer (score 0):

Есть три возможные проблемы:

1. Неверный порядок вызова скриптов (вы вызываете скрипт до того, как был инициализирован `GeoIPModule`)
2. Вы определили `GeoIPModule` локально, а не глобально, и поэтому второй скрипт не видит `GeoIPModule`
3. Вы где-то ошиблись в синтаксисе.

Предоставьте полный код страницы, тогда я смогу воспроизвести проблему и дать точный ответ.

Comment: Полный скрипт
https://jsfiddle.net/3L604e7m/